# Prevent certain folder from attaching cookies in request headers

Tags: performance, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have an application built with codeigniter and am running tests for rendering time etc, i have noticed that some certain static files have cookies attached to them which are adding unnecessary loading times.
I was wondering if it was possible to prevent requests to the folder from attaching cookies to the headers.
my site structure looks like this;

- application
- system
- assets
- assets/js
- assets/css
- assets/img
- profiles

I dont want requests to the assets and profiles folder to have cookies in their headers

Comment: you will have to place them on separate domian them .. as cookies will be sent by browser for ALL objects/resources from the same domain. That's why page Speed or Yahoo's YSlow will suggest placing them on separate domain -- to speed things up a bit (smaller request header)

Comment: @LazyOne i'll do that, i just presumed i could use a .htaccess file to modify the headers

Comment: And how .htaccess (on server) will prevent browser (client side) from **actually sending** cookies? It may remove them (so Apache will not see them) but that will achieve nothing.

Comment: You can specify a path to a cookie. So if for example you only need the cookie to be accessible by url starting with /application you could set the path for the cookie to /application. That way the cookie will not be sent by the browser for any other url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're setting cookies at the root, you'll need a separate hostname to do this.

I wouldn't serve the CSS from a separate hostname though...

After HTML, CSS is the next most important resource on a webpage as browser can't start rendering the page until it has the CSS.

If you serve the CSS from a separate domain then there's the overhear of resolving that domain and in some browsers the overhead of TCP connection set up (Chrome, IE9 and possibly other browsers speculatively open a second TCP connection to the host the HTML came from before they know they need it)

The CSS will still have the cookie set on it but if you set a long cache time for it, the CSS should only be requested once per session.

Comment: Just to clarify I would serve other static resources from another hostname particularly images...